# Eclipse IDE is stuck on building workspace

Tags: eclipse, maven, open-liberty

I have a problem in Eclipse 2019-09 after I migrated from WebSphere Application Server to Open Liberty server and switched from Jdk8 to Jdk11. Building the workspace is getting stuck forever. It works one time and then when I restart Eclipse, the problem of building the projects gets stuck forever and I have to terminate Eclipse and delete the .metadata folder for the workspace to be fixed.

For info, my workspace contains 29 java projects (web applications) and I'm using Maven to build it.

I also have tried to disable the validations, increased Eclipse's memory, deleted the indexes and history and disable building automatically.

Can someone help on that matter please?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The first thing would be to try using the current Eclipse 2023-03 rather than a release that is 4 years and 14 releases old

Comment: If you switch to the "Progress" view can you get a more detailed insight into what might be taking a long time?

Comment: @ScottKurz in the progress view I have the "Checking Files" and "Refreshing Workspace" both of them stuck after I restart Eclipse

Comment: I would try moving to a newer Eclipse if possible, like greg-449 suggested.  If you're trying to use the WebSphere/Liberty developer tooling you could try installing https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-liberty-developer-tools on top of the latest supported version:  2022-03 (4.23)

Comment: Use the current version of Eclipse (not the one you missed to keep up to date for years) and also a fresh workspace. Never ever delete the `.metadata` folder. That's a hoax spread on Stack Overflow.